# Your query does not include the specified expression 'regNo' as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to find the car within a database that has spent the most days in the garage, but I keep getting this error. Any ideas?

```
SELECT MAX((dateOut - dateIn)) AS [Number of Days], job.regNo, Garage.garageName
FROM Job, Garage
WHERE garage.garageID = job.garageID;
```

When running, I get the error "Your query does not include the specified expression 'regNo' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: Hi, you are using SQL aggregation function, which need `GROUP BY`,  you could read some tutorial here https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-group-by/

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want a list of all the jobs and how many days they took, you can do something like this:

```
select
    j.regNo,
    g.garageName,
    datediff(day,j.dateOut,j.dateIn) as [Number of Days]
from Job j
join Garage g on j.garageID = g.garageID
```

You do not specify your RDBMS, so I've assumed SQL Server above and used `datediff` to get the number of days between two dates. If you are using a different RDBMS, you may need to use a different function to achieve this, but I'm not aware of being able to directly subtract one datetime from another without some conversion or a function to do so.

I also replaced your multi-table `from` clause with a join and included aliases for the tables, as this is usually the preferred approach to querying multiple tables.

To answer you original question, you can use the query above with an `order by` and `top 1` to get what you're looking for:

```
select top 1
    j.regNo,
    g.garageName,
    datediff(day,j.dateOut,j.dateIn) as [Number of Days]
from Job j
join Garage g on j.garageID = g.garageID
order by datediff(day,j.dateOut,j.dateIn) desc
```